# How can I name a set of type bounds?

Tags: rust, traits

If I have a long list of type bounds that must be repeated in many places, how can I give them a name?

For example, what if instead of:

```rust
fn foo<T: Thing>(t: T) -> T
    where T: Copy, T: Debug { ... }
```

I want to write:

```rust
fn foo<T: Thing>(t: T) -> T
    where T: CopyDebug { ... }
```

where `CopyDebug` is defined to be `Copy+Debug`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using nightly Rust, you can use the nightly feature `trait_alias` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html)

```rust
trait CopyDebug = Copy + Debug;
```

And then any type satisfying both `Copy` and `Debug` will also satisfy `CopyDebug` automatically.

Because this feature is nightly, you need to put `#![feature(trait_alias)]` at the top of your crate main file.

Comment: from the docs: `These allow aliases to be created for one or more traits (currently just a single regular trait plus any number of auto-traits)` Thus it cannot be used with *any* number of traits, but just **one** normal trait and any number of auto-traits

Comment: Strange, because it works... (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=691b2554c05e45f307565fd96a0c0e56) Maybe the docs are outdated? @SvetlinZarev

Answer (score 7):

You can combine a list of type bounds into a single trait by creating an empty trait that requires the full list of type bounds on its implementer, like this:

```rust
trait MyCombination: A + B + C + D {}
impl<T: A + B + C + D> MyCombination for T {}
```

So in the case of `CopyDebug`, you can write:

```rust
trait CopyDebug: Copy + Debug {}
impl<T: Copy + Debug> CopyDebug for T {}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, but I marked [the answer about nightly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575743/2482570) as the selected answer because it may be more useful for Posterity if the feature lands.